# View not updating after getting values from store

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

In my MVVM app, when I create my viewmodel with a static method to load data from store and get notified, the view does not get updated when the notification arrives from the store.
The store uses the Lazy class.

What happens when I first load the viewmodel, the static viewmodel constroctor gets called first and then the OnCodeTypesLoaded gets called.
But when I switch beetween viewmodels, the view is displayed correctly, as inteded.
One solution that I found was is setting IsAsync to true in the XAML Binding, however, I don't think this is a good solutions, since it's looks flickery.
I have OnPropertyChanged of property of the viewmodels.

Dependecy Injection

```
services.AddSingleton<CreateViewModel<ProductViewModel>>(services => () => CreateProductViewModel(services));

private static ProductViewModel CreateProductViewModel(IServiceProvider services)
{
    return ProductViewModel.LoadProduct(services.GetRequiredService<IProductEndpoint>(),services.GetRequiredService<ICodeTypesStore>());
}
```

ProductViewModel

```
public class ProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IProductEndpoint _productEndpoint;
    private readonly ICodeTypesStore _codeTypesStore;

    public ProductViewModel(IProductEndpoint productEndpoint, ICodeTypesStore codeTypesStore)
    {
        _productEndpoint = productEndpoint;
        _codeTypesStore = codeTypesStore;
        _codeTypesStore.CodeTypesLoaded += OnCodeTypesLoaded;

        LoadProductCommand = new LoadProductCommand(this, productEndpoint);
        LoadCodeTypesCommand = new LoadCodeTypesCommand(codeTypesStore);
    }
    private void OnCodeTypesLoaded()
    {
        SystemTypes = _codeTypesStore.SystemTypes(SistemTypes.IT_Management);
        Product.SetNonExistantIdentifiers(SystemTypes);
    }
    public ICommand LoadProductCommand { get; }
    public ICommand LoadCodeTypesCommand { get; }
    
    public static ProductViewModel LoadProduct(IProductEndpoint productEndpoint, ICodeTypesStore codeTypesStore)
    {
        ProductViewModel viewModel = new ProductViewModel(productEndpoint,codeTypesStore);
        
        viewModel.LoadProductCommand.Execute(null);
        viewModel.LoadCodeTypesCommand.Execute(null);
        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

DisplayProduct Class

```
public class DisplayProduct : UI.Product
{
    public DisplayProduct(){}

    private List<UI.Sistem> _systems;
    public List<UI.Sistem> NonExistantIdentifiers { get; private set; }

    public DisplayProduct(UI.Product prd): base(prd.ID,prd.Name,prd.IsCompra,prd.IsProducao,prd.IsVenda,prd.Identifiers)
    {
    }
    
    public void SetNonExistantIdentifiers(List<UI.Sistem> systems)
    {
        _systems = systems;

        SetNonExistantIdentifiers();
    }
    private void SetNonExistantIdentifiers()
    {
        NonExistantIdentifiers = _systems.Where(s => !base.Identifiers.Select(x => x.System.ID).ToList().Contains(s.ID)).ToList();
    }

}
```

UserControl ProdctsNonLoaded

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFStuff.Controls.ProductIDsNonLoaded"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFStuff.Controls"
         xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:WPFStuff.Helpers"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NonExistantIdentifiers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Label"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Value"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBox MinWidth="150" helpers:SelectAllFocusBehavior.Enable="True">
                        <TextBox.Resources>
                            <helpers:BindingProxy x:Key="TargetProxy2" Data="{Binding RegExpression}"/>
                        </TextBox.Resources>
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    <helpers:CodeTypeValidationRule>
                                        <helpers:CodeTypeValidationRule.CodeTypePattern>
                                            <helpers:CodeTypeValidationParameter RegExPattern="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource TargetProxy2}}"/>
                                        </helpers:CodeTypeValidationRule.CodeTypePattern>
                                    </helpers:CodeTypeValidationRule>
                                </Binding.ValidationRules>
                            </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>


                </Grid>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

ProductView

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFStuff.Views.ProductView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFStuff.Views"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WPFStuff.Controls" xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:WPFStuff.Helpers"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         FontSize="20"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <controls:Product DataContext="{Binding Product}" />

    <WrapPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Grid.Row="1">
        <controls:ProductsIDs DataContext="{Binding Product}"  />
        <controls:ProductIDsNonLoaded DataContext="{Binding Product}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
    
</Grid>
```

CodeTypesStore

```
public class CodeTypesStore : ICodeTypesStore
{
    private readonly ICodeTypesEndpoint _codeTypesEndpoint;
    private readonly List<UI.Sistem> _systemCodeTypes;
    private readonly List<UI.CodeType> _productCodeTypes;

    private Lazy<Task> _loadCodeTypesLazy;

    public event Action CodeTypesLoaded;

    public CodeTypesStore(ICodeTypesEndpoint codeTypesEndpoint)
    {
        _codeTypesEndpoint = codeTypesEndpoint;
        _productCodeTypes = new();
        _systemCodeTypes = new();

        _loadCodeTypesLazy = CreateLoadCodeTypes();
    }
    private bool _isLoading;

    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get { return _isLoading; }
        set { _isLoading = value; }
    }

    public async Task LoadCodeTypes()
    {
        await _loadCodeTypesLazy.Value;
        CodeTypesLoaded?.Invoke();
    }

    private Lazy<Task> CreateLoadCodeTypes()
    {
        return new Lazy<Task>(() => InitializeCodeTypes());
    }

    private async Task InitializeCodeTypes()
    {
        IEnumerable<UI.Sistem> s = await _codeTypesEndpoint.GetSystemTypesCodes();
        IEnumerable<UI.CodeType> c = await _codeTypesEndpoint.GetProductsCodeTypes();

        _systemCodeTypes.Clear();
        _productCodeTypes.Clear();

        _systemCodeTypes.AddRange(s);
        _productCodeTypes.AddRange(c);

        //CodeTypesLoaded?.Invoke();
    }

    public List<UI.Sistem> SystemTypes(SistemTypes systemTypes)
    {
        return _systemCodeTypes.Where(sct => sct.SystemType?.SystemTypes == systemTypes).ToList();
    }
    public IEnumerable<UI.CodeType> ProductCodeTypes => _productCodeTypes;

}
```

Comment: Please post your code as a text, not as images.

Comment: Please post the code as text and format it as code. It is not allowed to post screenshots of code.

Comment: Please do not post code as images and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [why not to upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, I changed List to ObservableCollection in the DisplayProduct class

```
public DisplayProduct(){}

    private ObservableCollection<UI.Sistem> _nonExistantIdentifiers = new ObservableCollection<UI.Sistem>();
    public ObservableCollection<UI.Sistem> NonExistantIdentifiers 
    {
        get
        {
            return _nonExistantIdentifiers;
        }
        private set
        {
            _nonExistantIdentifiers = value;
        }
    }
       

    public DisplayProduct(UI.Product prd): base(prd.ID,prd.Name,prd.IsCompra,prd.IsProducao,prd.IsVenda,prd.Identifiers)
    {
    }
    public void SetNonExistantIdentifiers(List<UI.Sistem> systems)
    {
        var nonExistantIDs = systems.Where(s => !base.Identifiers.Select(x => x.System.ID).ToList().Contains(s.ID)).ToList();

        foreach (var item in nonExistantIDs)
        {
            _nonExistantIdentifiers.Add(item);
        }

        NonExistantIdentifiers = _nonExistantIdentifiers;
    }
}
```